# App coded on Xamarin ios AppStore reject reason EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, app-store, sigabrt

I've developed an Xamarin Forms App. Tested on simulator and physical device. Got no error.

I tested my app with debug on a physical device iPhone 6 and 7 on ios 10 and 11.
When I test on Testflight no errors given.

But when I try to publish on AppStore, they reject my app with this reason;

```
> {"app_name":"MyAppiOS","timestamp":"2017-10-11 14:40:11.93
> -0700","app_version":"1.0",.......,"build_version":"2","bundleID":"com.MyComp.MyApp1","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone
> OS 11.0.2 (15A421)",.....,"name":"MyAppiOS"} Incident Identifier:
> .................. CrashReporter Key:   .................. Hardware
> Model:      xxx Process:             MyAppiOS [1767] Path:            
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/........../MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS
> Identifier:          com.MyComp.MyApp1 Version:             2 (1.0)
> Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Role:                Foreground
> Parent Process:      launchd [1] Coalition:          
> com.MyComp.MyApp1 [1298]
> 
> 
> Date/Time:           2017-10-11 14:40:11.8427 -0700 Launch Time:      
> 2017-10-11 14:40:11.1613 -0700 OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0.2
> (15A421) Baseband Version:    6.17.00 Report Version:      104
> 
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0
> 
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
> 
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
```

Comment: Have you ever tested on iOS 11.0.2?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I tested it with 11.0.3, should I do with 11.0.2

Comment: Maybe it only appears in 11.0.2, it's worth to have a try.